# oracle sql extract the word before a specific word

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

Using oracle,
how to get a specific word before a word. i got a sample script that i found here but its in reverse(it gets the word after a specific word which is the CITY)

```
select regexp_substr ('TEXAS CITY CALIFORNIA', 'CITY[[:space:]]([[:alpha:]]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 test from dual;
```

result:
CALIFORNIA

what i want is to get is texas, but i need a dynamic script.

Answer (score 1):

Efficient way to achieve the desired result is to use `substr` and `instr` as follows:

```
substr('TEXAS CITY, CALIFORNIA',1, instr('TEXAS CITY, CALIFORNIA',' CITY'))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b70e4db342fe5980716d05f841bfa295)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract first word from any sentence with below code:

```
select regexp_substr ('TEXAS CITY, CALIFORNIA', '^[^ ]+',1 )test from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "CITY" won't always be the second word, this will get you only the word immediately preceding "CITY" for any string.

```
select regexp_substr (regexp_substr('TEXAS CITY, CALIFORNIA', '([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:]]CITY', 1), '^[^ ]+', 1)test from   dual
```

For more information, check out how regex works in Oracle SQL.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm

Comment: I'd say that your assumption is wrong. What if state name is NEW YORK? Your code returns just YORK.

Comment: @Littlefoot Since the query was for "the word preceding CITY", I'd think that in the case of NEW YORK CITY, the intended behavior would, in fact, be to return "YORK".

Comment: hahahah! Right, if we look at it that way, you're absolutely right, @Tyler :) Though, I still think that OP would actually want "New York" instead.